# ArangoDB and Gephi: Import data from ArangoDB into Gephi

Tags: visualization, graph-databases, arangodb, gephi, nosql

Is there a way to use ArangoDB as datasource for gephi? I tried https://github.com/datablend/gephi-blueprints-plugin/wiki . But it is only working with the indirection over rexster with included plugin blueprints-arangodb-graph.

I think this is very inelegant option with a lot overhead.

I wish some way, that I'm able to add a blueprints arango db plugin to gephi and then I'm able to choose a ArangoDB as datasource. Maybe in combination with gephi-blueprints-plugin.

I think a combination of the blueprints plugin for gephi and the arangodb blueprints API would be the nicest solution to avoid an additional step over a csv (or other) file to work with data from ArangoDB in Gephi.

The description of the blueprints plugin for gephi says: "The Gephi Blueprints plugin allows a user to import graph-data from any graph database that implements the Tinkerpop Blueprints generic graph API". But I don't know how - it supports out of the box only TinkerGraph, Neo4j, OrientDB, Dex, RexterGraph and FluxGraph.

I tried to create a arrangodb.xml in /etc/graph and add the blueprints implementation of arrangodb as jar in the ".gephi/dev/modules" folder. But gephi doesn't load the jar and so the menu entry "Import/Graph database ..." and the selection of "arangodb" leads to a null pointer error because of the missing class file the arangodb blueprints api.

Has someone worked with gephi-blueprints-plugin and/or blueprints-arangodb-graph and has some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This was discussed on [this ticket](https://github.com/triAGENS/blueprints-arangodb-graph/issues/7) of the Blueprints Adapter of ArangoDB. A plugin for Gephi has to be build specifically for ArangoDB. [Axel Hoffmann](https://github.com/hoffmaaxe) is thinking about developing this plugin.